# Only Using for loops to print the codes

Tags: java, for-loop

I need to get the result using for loop
Let's say i have these 2 variables

My concerns are Enter the type#1 then #2.

Another is getting the result.

this is my code so far.

```
int morning =23, Nighttime =45;


for(int i=0 ; i<1; i++ )
{      
     System.out.println("Enter  type #1:" +Morning);
     System.out.println("Enter  type #2:" +Morning);
     System.out.println("Enter  type #3:" +Nighttime);
}
```

So i want to print this output.

Enter the type #1: 23

Enter the type #2: 23

Enter the type #3: 45

Result:

2 morning

1 Nighttime

*Apologies to all, this is the edited version. Any advice is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

morning not Morning **variables are case sensitive in JAVA**

```
int morning =23, Nighttime =45;


for(int i=0 ; i<1; i++ )
{      
     System.out.println("Enter  type #1:" +morning);
     System.out.println("Enter  type #2:" +morning);
     System.out.println("Enter  type #3:" +Nighttime);
}
```

Comment: As you can see, for loop only requires 1 system.out.println but i put 3 which i don think is correct. Need clarification on this.

Comment: If you want to get user input and then print you have to look into different perceptive of getting user input in java

Comment: if possible don follow my codes, and do it based on the outputs. cause i just testing using my codes, but i don think is correct. Mind if i can have look at your codes?

Answer (score 0):

for the output you say you want,

```
for(int i=0 ; i<1; i++ )
{      
     System.out.println("Enter  type #1:\"" +" +Morning");

}
```

and so on...
I'm not sure how you expect to get "2 morning 1 Nighttime" because you are not maintaining any variables to count them!

EDTED:
Here for your edited question,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class My {

    int morning = 23, Nighttime = 45;
    static int mCount = 0;
    static int nCount = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter  type #" + i + ":");
            int a = s.nextInt();
            if (a == 23) {
                mCount += 1;
            } else {
                nCount += 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(mCount + " Morning");
        System.out.println(nCount + " Night");
    }
}
```

Comment: but do u think is an efficient way to print out 3 system.out.print? instead of 1? i am just roughly doing the codes. just want to get a general idea of doing. Any advice is recommended.

Comment: I honestly do not understand how you're expecting the output,so it is difficult to recommend anything! Anyway if you don't want three print statement,make (i<3) and System.out.println("Enter  type #"+i+":\"" +" +Morning");

Comment: i mean don follow my codes. try to solve it using the output i have shown. i just want to have an idea how to solve it.

Comment: how you got you are first two morning and last nighttime?

Comment: exactly, is like i key in the numbers 23 and 45. the result will prompt the 2 mornings and 1 nighttime.

Comment: use Scanner,look up, I gave the answer!

Comment: just want to know why the initialize variables is at the bottom of public class, shouldn't it be at the public static void main? and if i were to change, underline codes appear.

Comment: Hi, is there a way if u don't include static int mCount and static int nCount?